# How to design your viewmodel for a time table?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, viewmodel

I have a timetable for student so they can attend to course on the week.
And I don't know how I should build my ViewModel.

I decided this :

```
class CourseTableViewModel
{
    CourseTableHeaderViewModel[] Headers;
    CourseTableRowViewModel[] Rows;
}

class CourseTableRowViewModel
{
    int HourStart;
    CourseTableCellViewModel[] Cells;
}

class CourseTableHeaderViewModel
{
    DateTime Date;
}

class CourseTableCellViewModel
{
    CourseViewModel[] Courses;//null if no course at this time
}
```

but for me it seems like to heavy for my view model. Maybe I should only send the CourseViewModel[] and then on my cshtml do all the table/row/cell work.

Does the viewmodel should really look like my view ?

EDIT : I'll show my data as a Time Table with the days of the week as headers, and a row foreach hour of the day.
If a course take 2 hour it'll occupy 2 rows.
There'll be a button "Attend" or "Cancel" on each course's cell.

PS : I know about jquery fullcalendar, but I'm just trying to learn how to build my viewmodel here.

Comment: The answer depends on how you intend to present the data to the user and what UI will be there for editing (if any). Start with specifying that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> but for me it seems like to heavy for my view model. Maybe I should
>   only send the CourseViewModel[] and then on my cshtml do all the
>   table/row/cell work.

The way you build your ViewModel MUST NOT depend on the way the View is organized, otherwise you break separation of concerns between View and Controller.
The fact that you decided to use a kind of table to show your courses MUS NOT be reflected on the ViewModel, otherwise a change in the way the View is organized would cause a chain reaction on the controller code.

Pass to the View just ALL INFORMATION it needs to render the courses, and then, in the View do all JOB that is needed to show your table.

Doing transformations of data in the View may cause problems when you are in edit mode because the inverse transformation is not applied by the model binder when it receives the posted data. If you have this problem give a look to Mvc Controls Toolkit in-line transformations there: http://mvccontrolstoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=In-Line%20Transformations

Comment: There is 1 ViewModel for each View so yes my viewmodel depends on my view ! The way I build my viewmodel is not defined in my controller but in my viewmodel ( or my viewmodel factory), the controller only deals with models objects and calls constructor or factory for mapping them from/to the viewmodel.

Comment: "There is 1 ViewModel for each View so yes my viewmodel depends on my view" 
The one to one mapping in itself doesn't imply that the ViewModel depends on the View! You deisgn the Viewmodel starting from the specification of WHAT to SHOW on the page, then you design the controller as you explained. AT THE END you design the View by deciding HOW to show WHAT you have already decided to show, and put in the ViewModel.
If after using your system for say some months the customer say  that he doesn't like the table you can JUST CHANGE THE VIEW to display the same information in a different way.

Comment: @remibourgarel You now have two people telling the same thing in two different ways.  Your over cooking this and worrying about things that are not an issue.  You VM design lows RoI, code makes money, Q.E.D.  Make life simple and when you're ask to change the view, do that, change the view only and not the view, VM, controller/action, etc.  Francesco is right, give it all the info and let the view do it's job.

Comment: @jolySoft, actually Francesco is right because in his solution I don't send the Model to the view. it's just I'm beginning with asp.net mvc and I read every where that any code in my view is a mistake, it should only contain display instruction, but I might have over applied this principle. thanks

Answer (score 5):

Some of the view model class are too light; CourseTableHeaderViewModel.  As Jon stated you need to think about the UI will display this data but I would not have headers and row separate but have a class (domain preferably) that represents all the data you will need and then the vi9ew model is a list of these classes:

```
public class Course {
    public int Id {get; set; }
    public DateTime StartTime {get; set; }
    public string Name {get; set; }
    . . . 
    . . .
}

public class CoursesViewModel {
    public List<Course> Courses {get; set; }
    public object SomeReferenceData {get; set; }
    . . . 
    . . . 
}
```

Dependent on how you want to display the data you could sort the courses list using linq then you assign it into the model.

Comment: That would force me to put a lot of logic into my .cshtml file like the linq for getting a course at a particular day/hour/

Comment: No not really.  That, as I say, could be done at you assign the courses into the model or server-side via ajax.  If you're going to cut the data different ways you'll always have that problem

Comment: I won't load my time table cell by cell, in my time table I have days a column and hours as rows, with your solution i'll have to put all the logic "which course for which cell" into my view. And in your solution there is reference of the model class in the view model which is IMHO a bad practice : just send to the view what it needs.

Comment: I use razor not velocity therefore I don't mind a little logic there.  IMHO you are giving the view what it needs and letting the view cut that.  If you don't want any logic in the view then use something nVelocity and put all the rend er logic in helper (painful).  Or just admit you need a little logic there, your model doesn't adhere to KISS IMHO and we are only talking about a linq statement in you loop.  Anyway best of luck.

Comment: Agreed. I wouldn't split your view models up to fit the view to such a level. Pass the view your data and let it handle it. What if later on you wanted to display this data as a drop-down or something? All you would have to do is change the View, not the model as well.

Comment: the model and the viewmodel are two separate things. The viewmodel is part of the view, it's just the computing part of the view, the view only browse the viewmodel and display it.

Comment: @remibourgarel I'm an old monoRail dev and M$ Mvc has the concept of the viewmodel (I believe to make it more accessable to people from an MVVM background) but this is a Model-View-Controller pattern from 1979 and a view can have many models (else you might as well do MVP). VM gives value add by strongly typing views and IMHO are aggregation of Model objects and NOT a remapping exercise.  This isn't WebForms